# how to extract the value of a parameter within a parameter and then print in ant

Tags: ant

I want to write a code in such a way that I will remove platform from first 3 lines and then take only the platform name and I will suffix that with `installer-zip.${platform_name}`.

```
platform.win-x86=true
platform.win-x64=true
platform.unix=false
installer-zip.win-x86=E:\abc.jar
installer-zip.win-x64=E:\def.jar
```

Now if the selected item is win-x86 then printing `installer-zip.${platform_name}` should give me `E:\abc.jar`. I tried `${installer-zip.${platform_name}}` and many other things but they are not working

Comment: Please reformat your question. It is barely readable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just a friendly reminder: You can [accept answers that helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160062) on your previous questions. You haven't accepted a single answer.

Comment: No Ant doesn't support nested property conversion.

Comment: And please stop posting variations on the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with regular ant, but you can do this with [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/).

In particular, there is a contrib task [property-regex](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html).

So something like:

```
<propertyregex property="$newProperty" 
               input="$oldProperty" 
               regexp="^platform\.(,*)$"
               select="\1"
               casesensitive="false" />
```

EDIT: and then...

```
<property name=desiredProperty value="installer-zip.${newProperty}" />
```

That should give you enough to work out the exact solution you're looking for...

Comment: that way i will be able to extract the platform names only

Comment: then you can create the full property by compounding this platform name with the other parts of your desired property string

Comment: you could even pass a property into the regexp of the propertyregex task... which on further reading of your problem looks like what you need to do...